# Instagram integration fails in iOS by using webView

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

In my application i was doing Instagram authentication  using webView .first it was showing Instagram login screen ,after successfully login i was fetching accessToken then i fetched other details using the accessToken.

here is my loadrequest method which i am calling in viewDidLoad

```
func loadrequest(){

        let authURL = String(format: "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@", arguments: [INSTAGRAM_API.INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,INSTAGRAM_API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI, INSTAGRAM_API.INSTAGRAM_SCOPE ])
        let urlRequest =  URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: authURL)!)
        instaWebview.loadRequest(urlRequest)

    }
```

here is my webViewDelegate methods where i am calling checkRequestForcallBackURL method

```
  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
       return checkRequestForcallBackURL(request: request)
    }
```

inthis method i am checking whether iam getting  my accesstoken or not

```
   func checkRequestForcallBackURL(request : URLRequest) ->Bool{

            let requestURLString = (request.url?.absoluteString)! as String

            if requestURLString.hasPrefix(INSTAGRAM_API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI) {
                let range: Range<String.Index> = requestURLString.range(of: "#access_token=")!

  handleAuth(authToken: requestURLString.substring(from: range.upperBound))
        return false;
    }

        return true
    }
```

Now while login its asking security code ,after giving security code it redirects me to Instagram App which i don't want .I don't know how to proceed further

Comment: There is temporary an issue with Instagram that they keep asking for the security code and not providing access token. hope they will resolve it soon. This is happening only for some usernames you can try some others to check your code.

Comment: @MayankBarnwal ,hey i tired few other account also but could not able  fetch code or accesstoken ,it only redirect me to instagram app only

Comment: @shaki have you tried with some other client id? I am trying with this link https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token and is working good. You can add scope also.

Comment: @MayankBarnwal yes i tired with other client id, same thing happened  but i am not able to get code or #accesstoken ,but i am redirecting to instagram App only what to do

Answer (score 1):

I implement Instagram login in one my application. What i do is. for getting instagram token simply present new ViewController with webview and load instagram login page.

```
let authURL = String(format: "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True", arguments: [INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI, INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_SCOPE ])
    let urlRequest =  URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: authURL)!)
    web_instaView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

then in webview delegate method

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: request)
}


func checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: URLRequest) -> Bool {

    let requestURLString = (request.url?.absoluteString)! as String

    if requestURLString.hasPrefix(INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI) {
        let range: Range<String.Index> = requestURLString.range(of: "#access_token=")!
        handleAuth(authToken: requestURLString.substring(from: range.upperBound))
        return false;
    }
    return true
}

func handleAuth(authToken: String)  {
    print("Instagram authentication token ==", authToken)
    INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_USER_TOCKEN = authToken
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(INSTAGRAM_IDS.INSTAGRAM_USER_TOCKEN, forKey: "INSTAGRAM_USER_TOCKEN")
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("instaLoginDone"), object: nil)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

after getting instagram token, i simple dismiss that ViewController and save Token locally. Than fetch user info in background mode and show loader or whatever you want.

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: hey i did the exact same thing man forgot to mention about handleAuth method

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a `WKWebView` and after the user enters their security code, I implement `WKWebViewDelegate` `decidePolicyFor` and look for the `https://www.instagram.com` redirect which I don't allow and instead send them back to the original authentication URL which now, since they've entered the code, works.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if let url = navigationAction.request.url, url.absoluteString == "https://www.instagram.com/" {
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        webView.load(scheme.authenticationURlRequest)
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: hey are you getting the code ? if yes can you please share the code

Comment: according to instagram developer docs https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/
 there is two ways either Server-side (Explicit) Flow, where you have to **response_type=code** and in Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication ,you have to write **response_type=token**

Comment: So from the first  method we got  the code  from the  redirect Url Followed by =CODE like this **http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE**,after getting the code we hit **https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token** and do our stuffs  but in method two we directing get accesstoken  **http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN**

Answer (score 0):

Good news ,Now i think instagram changed its policy ,now we are getting code and accesstoken

Comment: this problem occurs with suspicious account where after login screen instagram is  asking security  code then it redirects the user to instgram app only