# WKWebView SWIFT: not show messages in instagram

Tags: swift, xcode, instagram, message, wkwebview

I'm a new in Swift/iOS developing. I try to create a simple browser:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!
    
    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
    
}
```

When I go to https://www.instagram.com, I can't see my messages.

I got this (**top header isn't shown**):

[image]

But I expect this (**top header is shown**):

[image]

Why I can't see the top header through my browser?

Comment: Follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145916/instagram-integration-fails-in-ios-by-using-webview

Comment: @ShashankMishra can you explain please? I don't have problems with instagram authentication, I login successfully. So, I don't understand your link.

Comment: @ShashankMishra I don't use Instagram API. I try to create a simple browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to see the header at my end. The only difference is that I've added WKWebView in XIB and you are loading on view from the code.

Reason can be the frame & constraints of the page. Try setting frame & constraints -

```
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Comment: Yes, almost this, but you are right 100%, problem was in frame & constraints. Navigation Bar overlapped with top header. Thank you.